# PYTHON: Connection check with socket and VM

Tags: python, sockets, virtual-machine

i have a local machine `IP: 192.168.1.150` and a VM `IP:192.168.1.152`.

I'd like to check if the connection exists with my ubuntu server (by the way my ubuntu server is installed on the VM) or not:

My Code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

    import os
    import sys
    import socket

    SERVER_IP = '192.168.152'
    SERVER_PORT = 80

    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    s.bind((SERVER_IP, SERVER_PORT))
    print('Connected')
    s.close()
```

but sadly it doen't work and i get the ERROR:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./checkConnectionToServer.py", line 11, in <module>
    s.bind((SERVER_IP, SERVER_PORT))
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied
```

Comment: Do you have the necessary permissions to perform this action?

Comment: what do you mean with 'necessary permissions'?

Comment: the error is permission denied. Do you have the permissions to perform the action. A way to test is if you can check this manually. Maybe this is an admin-only type task, etc.

Comment: Checked and now i get this:

OSError: [Errno 98] Address already in use

Comment: It is completely unclear to me which machine is the server and which machine is the client, and where this code is supposed to run. If this is supposed to be the client then you need to study a sockets tutorial first, I'm afraid you are a long way off from making a connection to port 80 of your peer.